# How to convert SSL certificates generated to PKCS12

Tags: ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

I got the crt+ca bundle and private key from https://punchsalad.com/ssl-certificate-generator/, I wonder how to convert the files into PKCS12 which I can use in SpringBoot?

I found online tutorials only mention .pem format and the following instruction needs chain.pem. I wonder how to get this file.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.pfx -inkey privkey.pem -in cert.pem -certfile chain.pem
```

Relevant links:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Glad to help you,
I just ran into this problem.

The ssl files obtained from https://punchsalad.com/ssl-certificate-generator/ are txt files containing ca-bundle.txt and private-key.txt

To convert to pfx, just change the downloaded txt file ca-bundle.txt to certificate.crt, private-key.txt to private.key and enter the following command.

```
sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out FILE.pfx -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt
```

-certfile command is options.

I am successful when uploading pfx in Azure Web App Service.